# Typing ' twice turns it into ´

Tags: keyboard

I am having a very minor problem.

When I press ' (single quote) twice, it turns into a ´ (like that thing under ~ but reversed; I don even know the name which is probably why I haven't found a solution).

Is there a way to get simply '' when pressing ' twice?

Thanks in advance!

- I tried keyboard set to `English (US International)` and `English (UK)`

Comment: Can you provide in what language you have your keyboard layout?

Comment: Ah sorry for the trouble but I just found that the problem was actually gone with `English (UK)` setting! My bad, I probably needed to confirm or close or something, or just plain tested it wrongly.

Comment: That character is 0xB4, ACUTE ACCENT.

Comment: Hi, may I know how did you get rid of the problem? I did not know what shortcut I have accidentally hit and now my ' becomes to ´ as well, and I try to change the input source to English (US) and English (UK), and it dose not work.

Comment: Alt Gr with dead keys works in Ubuntu 23

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On US-International keyboard, pressing `'` (single quote) makes an accent when you press  `a` or `e` or a few other keys after it. To make a single quote you need to press `'` followed by `space`. For double quote, it's the same thing, you press `"` followed by a `space`. To have 2 single quotes, you need to press `'`, `space`, `'`, `space`.
This is useful only if you use accentued languages (like French or Portuguese). If not, I think US Keyboard (and probably UK keyboard) is better.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, in ubuntu 14.04, the ibus seems stopped after I by accident changed the keyboard to English (US, international with dead keys). So even when I change the keyboard input to English (US) again, the issue still exists. Because the keyboard dost not change. After I started the ibus :

```
ibus-daemon &
```

then the problem solved.